# cannot create a directory using mkdir

Tags: php, mysql, directory, mkdir

So I'm trying to develop a script where all users can upload an image to a dynamically created folder.

Here is the line I made.

```
$newID = 1
mkdir('uploads/job_images/'.$newID.'/',0755);
```

This will create a folder inside "uploads/job_images" which is already set up.

My problem is that if "job images" permission is set to 755 or 766 it wont let me create a directory.
But when I try to set the "job_images" permission to 777 it allows me to create a directory. But they say 777 is a security risk. Why do you think I cant create a folder inside "job_images" if permission is set to 755 but allows me to create a folder inside "job_images" if "job_images" permission is set to 777?

The created folder also have the "owner/group" set to 99/99(nobody). Is that owner group okay?

Questions:

1. Can I do it without using 777 to "job_images" folder or leaving it to 777 is okay?
2. Do I need to change the owner of the created folder? I might someday need to delete those folders.
3. How do I default the group of those created folders by the users of the website?

Comment: What user/group is your webserver running under?  If not 99/99 try setting the ownership of the folder to your webserver user/group

Comment: dont know more. but is there any permission required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `sudo`[`chown`](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html) to change the ownership of your directory to Apache (or whatever software/service/daemon running your code :). If you are the creator of the directory, you don't need to use sudo (but in most Unix/Linux system you'll need to have the target group permissions too).

Please read about [Numeric Notation of filesystem permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Numeric_notation). The first 7 indicating that the **owner group** have right to Read, Write and Execute your file. 5 means Read & Execute, without write, so you can't make new directory.

Comment: Hello, I dont have access to root. I only have a re seller account from a hosting provider. Every now and then new folders are being created by different users does it mean I need to change the group owner of those newly created folder everynow and then?

Comment: Hi, if you are the owner of the file - you still can use the chown command to change the owner. In most Unix/Linux system you need to have the target user/group permissions too.

Comment: "5 means Read & Execute, without write, so you can't make new directory."

So that means there is no other way to create a new directory inside a folder if that folder is set to 755? I'm sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: The first number reffered to owner, the second one is to the owner group and the third one is to everyone. So only the owner of the file can create new folders (which requests "Write" privileges) :)

Answer (score 0):

I`ve the same problem, PHP restrict some functions:

[Functions restricted by safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php)
The solution is set the directive safe_mode_gid=On in the /etc/php5/apache2/phi.ini configuration file.

See [safe_mode_gid directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)
It works for my LAMP server Ubuntu 12.04